# Flow type image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have the following code:

`const imageLoader: HTMLImageElement = new Image();`

This throws the following Flow error:

```
Cannot assign `new Image()` to `imageLoader` because `Image` [1] is incompatible with `HTMLImageElement` [2]. (References: [1] [2])
```

I can't find any information about `HTMLImageElement` or images generally in the [Flow documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/). I did however find `HTMLImageElement` on this [Flow cheatsheet](https://www.saltycrane.com/flow-type-cheat-sheet/latest/).

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image):

```
The Image() constructor creates a new HTMLImageElement instance.
```

Is this a bug in Flow or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `const imageLoader: Image = new Image();`?

Comment: @Tholle Yes I did. It stops the above error, but then I can't do `imageLoader.addEventListener` without it erroring with `Cannot call 'imageLoader.addEventListener' because property 'addEventListener' is missing in 'Image'`

Comment: @Coop have you tried to call the constructor on the `window.Image` instead of simple `Image`?